# using UPDATE, SELECTand INSERT INTO statements altogther in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have an MS access project in which the tabel of transactions contains as many as 70 records per day. they are common in one parameter, the Date of today.

the normal way to start entering data is to go to teh table and copy records of yesterday then paste them as new records, then changing date from yesterday to today date.

What I need is to use SQL statements to achieve this. I can say that

step 1: use insert into to input the new records in the table.
Step 2: use update statement to change the date.
Step 3: use the select statement to select the records which will have the date to be changed.
How to combine the use of these statements altogther.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need something on the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Field, Field, Field, ADate)
SELECT Field,Field,Field,Date() As ADate
FROM Table WHERE ADate = Date()-1
```

Or just change the default value of the date field in the table to Date(), or Now(), and only insert the other fields. Date will then be automatically filled in as today.

Comment: What part do you not understand?